# Fast RF switching (Q-switching)

Tags: rf, switching, solid-state-relay

First question so feel free to ask for additional info if something is unclear. Quite a green EE that is very new to RF applications.

To provide some background: I am working on improving a substance detection method.
[image]
The gist of it is that with the circuit in the image above, an insignal  that is carefully generated excites a substance placed in the L1 coil. This can be a 500 kHz - 2 MHz signal up to 600 V, and instantaneous power can be around 100 W, in microsecond pulse trains but it all depends on what to measure. The measurement is then made by the **same** coil. This setup is adequate for most cases but for some, the samples have a very short time window to pick up good signals. This is where the problem comes, since I want to begin measurements sooner due to the nature of the sample I get too low SNR because the coil is still ringing. You can lower the Q-factor of the coil to shorten this but that would make it harder to pick up sample signal. Thus I am trying to make an "active Q-switch" that can **dump energy left in the coil in a microsecond(s) window** (lower Q temporarliy). After that restore high Q-factor to measure the sample.

To visualize, I am trying to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I have tried methods of rectifying the pulse before dumping. Half and full, see image below for example, hastily made for post. All subpar due to difficulties of impedance matching that lower the Q-factor all the time or introduce some noise during the measurement time. My inexperience with what components are appropriate for this problem also doesn’t help.

[image]

(All by TTL from delay generator)

I have considered using some proper solid state relays (SSR), TRIACS etc. instead and wonder what would be appropriate for an application with these specifications? Is the rectifier method or just an SSR etc. better to go for? Or is there perhaps another way entirely to accomplish this?

Thank you for reading, any input is very welcome. I will provide more info if needed.

Comment: your problem may be suitable for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if you placed a critically-damped resistor value on the ground leg of the capacitor, shorted it out for the initial pulse, then briefly opened it (allowed the resistor to waste most of the ringing energy) then closed it again.